# How does flash loading time effect timed .delay elements?

Tags: jquery, flash, timedelay

I will do my best to articulate this question properly. I have a page that is loading in a narration audio file(simple flash player playing a compressed .mp3), which I then sync up with points that appear on the screen. I am using the .delay in jQuery to achieve this.

My issue is that the load time of the flash object is not standard and will throw off the display of the timed tags.

Is there a way to have the delay only start after the flash object has started playing?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on flowPlayer

http://flowplayer.org/demos/plugins/flash/load-swf.html

With this js You can controll when flash plays or loads

Answer (score 0):

You could try loading the flash element with jQuery and then use the callback function. The flash video will need to be on auto-play. Just an idea, haven't tried this.

`$("#flash").load("flash.html", function(){ // Your delayed stuff });`